# How to convert varchar to number

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have character string as '00000625710' I want it as number 6257.10 how can I do that . I tried as follow 
`select to_number('00000002511','999999999.99')from dual;`

But didn't work . can any one help me in this . Thank you.

Comment: "didn't work" is not a useful diagnostic message. Presumably it gave you 2511 instead of 25.11?

Comment: Please include in your questions ***explicitly*** what is happening, including any error messages, as well as why it's not you wanted.  Reproducibility is one of the fundamental aspects of reporting issues and allowing others to make a diagnosis for you.  See also "verifiable" here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the least 2 characters are always decimal (more generally, that the structure of your input strings is fixed), you can simply divide:

```
select to_number('00000002511') / 100 from dual;
```